# Can't package react native because of port 8081 sunproxyadmin

Tags: macos, react-native

when I run this in terminal:

lsof -n -i4TCP:8081

I get this

```
node      10901 me   28u  IPv6 0xbcad49      0t0  TCP *:sunproxyadmin (LISTEN)
foo 11957 me   15u  IPv4 0xbcad49      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:61127->127.0.0.1:sunproxyadmin (CLOSE_WAIT)
```

What is this sunproxyadmin?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Per http://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml?search=8081, TCP port 8081 is the well known port for sunproxyadmin the same way 80 is the well known port for http.  In this case, you have a node process that is listening on port 8081, but lsof is trying to be helpful and show the well known port for this.  Under linux, this is defined in /etc/services; I would expect OS X is similar.

Edit 1: Note that per [Apple Man Pages](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/lsof.8.html), passing `-P`

> inhibits the conversion of port numbers to port names for  network  files.
>   Inhibiting  the conversion  may  make  lsof run a little faster.  It
>   is also useful when port name lookup is not working properly.

This should cause lsof to not print out the confusing sunproxyadmin for something that just happens to use the port that Sun registered.

Edit 2: The second column in your response (e.g. 10901 in the first row, which is the one you want, and 11957 in the second row) should be the process ID.  If you do `ps aux | grep 10901` (or `ps elf | grep [pid]`, as I can't remember which works right for OSX and don't have it handy) you should get something like:

> apache   19783  0.0  0.2 251888  8580 ?        S    Oct07   0:00
>   /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND

(or to make something up:

> nodeuser   10901  0.0  0.2 251888  8580 ?        S    Oct07   0:00 node index.js

)

You can kill it with `kill -9 10901` (or whatever the PID was) though you might find it comes back if it's running as a service or what.

This is useful enough to add to your bash profile:

```
function findbyport()
{
  sudo lsof -P -iTCP:$1 -sTCP:LISTEN
}
```

Comment: What node process is this and how can I get rid of it?

Comment: I've done this and it works ending with [6:22:45 PM] <END>   request:/index.ios.bundle (157ms)

However when running in xcode I don't see the latest version of my app in the iphone emulator

Answer (score 4):

Kill it, do in your terminal

```
sudo lsof -i :8081
```

from there get the PID number and then run

```
kill -9 <PID NUMBER>
```

You can check on [FB documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/troubleshooting.html) for more info

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to kill `sunproxyadmin` process, let try to start React native in different port with command:
`react-native start --port your_port`

Then open `Dev settings` (see [how to open dev menu](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging.html)), and modify **Debug server host & port for device** to: `your_local_ip:your_port`

Answer (score 1):

There is this MACAFEE antivirus running on my Mac. *I am able to kill it(Even though I should not be killing it, I tried it, and looks like it never dies! Sudo has no power after all!)*.So after a lot of research I have tried this one.

**Step 1** : Get the process' PID
sudo lsof -n -i4TCP:8081
**Step 2** : Find the launchd endpoint
sudo launchctl list | grep 
**Step 3** : Remove mcafee
sudo launchctl remove com.mcafee.agent.macmn

If this one works for you pls say thanks to me and as well as https://fantashit.com/unable-to-perform-react-native-start/